# How to see through two cameras simultaneously?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

In my scene I have two cameras (let's say `camera1` and `camera2`), and in my GUI I have two panes both displaying the *3D-View*.

In the first pane I'd now like to see through `camera1`. This can easily be done by activating `camera1` by selecting it, pressing <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 0</kbd> (or if it is already active, just pressing <kbd>NumPad 0</kbd>). The problem comes with the second camera: When I try to activate it, both panes automatically switch to the perspective of the second camera. Is there a way to avoid this, such that both panes show the corresponding perspectives?

[image: problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just unclick this button from both the windows. That will break the link. Press <kbd>Ctrk</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> in 1 window

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Blender 2.8, you need to select a local camera in the view sidebar, as answered [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126407/different-cameras-on-different-viewports-blender-2-8?newreg=2996d8cb9f6d4e9d922a66b442dd8c6e).