# Different Cameras on different Viewports ? Blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, camera

How to get this different cameras in different viewports in blender 2.8?

From docuemntaion:
"Local Camera
Active camera used in this view to override the (global) scene camera. The option is available only when **lock local camera and layers toggle in the header** is not" 
enabled.[image]

Where is this option lock local camera...?

Comment: This feature is not (yet) available in Blender 2.80. The documentation you refer to gives instructions on how to enable this feature in 2.79. There you need to have local layers enabled (which is a button ín the header of the 3D View), and then set the active camera for each view in the dropdown box.

Comment: I wish use blender for animating videomapping (with two projectors), and display blenders viewports on fullscreen from projectros to physical objects(realtime render with eevee), but I can only one viewport camera active :(  Okey, so i must waiting...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In sidebar options (N button) you have to select Use Local Camera and select your camera. See image.
[image: Use Local Camera]

Comment: This solution is also elaborated in this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIjeXFZVrLU&t=1s

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ambiguous as to what you're asking, but you can

1. Go to a viewport and press numpad 0 to go to the view of the active camera.
2. Go to the other viewport, select the other camera, and do Ctrl + numpad 0 to set that as the active camera.
3. Press numpad 0 to set that viewport to the view of the active camera.

[How can I make a camera the active one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one)

I'm afraid that I haven't been able to test it as I don't have access to Blender at the moment, but I've done research and I believe this should work.