# render doesn't look like viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Blender 2.8, cycles
I'm trying to get a height map from a mesh.  The tute I am following is here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekogw2Zm20Y

I have two meshes in scene, a grid (flat) and a 3D mesh.  I have a couple cameras in scene and a sun lightsource.

In the viewport I can see the object with material color assigned to it.  My camera is above the object.  Camera view shows the object. Camera is set to orthographic.

When I render (Render > Render Image), I get a grey screen.
What am I doing wrong that my render looks nothing like my view port, and how do I make things so the render shows what I see in the view port?

Willing to share blend file as it's just a test, but I probably don't have enough rep for that.

Thx

[image: viewport screenshot]

[image: render image result]

Comment: In your second screenshot the camera isn't set active. Are you sure that it was active when you rendered the image?

Comment: I'm guessing it wasn't.  I don't have the viewport vs camera thing down yet.  I was able to get what I expected when I made the camera active using this thread:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126407/different-cameras-on-different-viewports-blender-2-8/150983#150983.  Thx